# iOS Creating a dynamic textfield thats numeric only

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently my application dynamically creates textfields. Some of these fields will allow all characters, but some of them I want to only be numeric (or any character set I choose).

I found the following code on here:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    //Allows backspace
    if([string length]==0){
        return YES;
    }

    //Character set limits to numeric characters
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

This is where the textfield is being created:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, 30)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

But I am not quite sure how to implement this into a dynamically created textfield?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"]` is the same as `[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` Also, your code does not do what you want: it returns `YES` if it finds at least one digt; if you want all digits, the `for` loop needs to change.

Comment: Yeah, but this is just an example, I will be making changes to allowed characters soon. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that method to be called on the textfield, you need to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in your ViewController, and set the `delegate` property of the textfield to be the ViewController.

```
@interface DemoViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

And then in the implementation:

```
textfield.delegate = self;
```

That should work. Untested but fairly simple.